# Continuing execution even if assert statement fails in selenium using Junit 4 framework

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, ui-testing

In my test case its compulsory to use multiple assertions. Problem is that if one assertion fails then execution stops. I want that test case continue to execute even after encountering assertion failure, and it shows all assertion failure after execution.

For example :

```
assertTrue("string on failure",condition1);
assertTrue("string on failure",condition2);
assertTrue("string on failure",condition3);
assertTrue("string on failure",condition4);
assertTrue("string on failure",condition5);
```

Here in this example i want that if assert fails for condition2 , then it should continue to execute and show all failures after complete execution.

Answer (score 4):

For a purely JUnit solution, use the **ErrorCollector** TestRule to handle your asserstions.

The **ErrorCollector** Rule does not report back until the test execution completes.

```
import org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual;
import org.hamcrest.core.IsNull;
import org.hamcrest.text.IsEmptyString;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector;

public class ErrorCollectorTest {
    @Rule
    public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

    @Test
    public void testMultiAssertFailure() {
        collector.checkThat(true, IsEqual.equalTo(false));
        collector.checkThat("notEmpty", IsEmptyString.isEmptyString());
        collector.checkThat(new Object(), IsNull.nullValue());
        collector.checkThat(null, IsNull.notNullValue());

        try {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception");
        } catch (Exception ex){
            collector.addError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

---

In your specific example:

```
assertTrue("string on failure",condition1);
assertTrue("string on failure",condition2);
assertTrue("string on failure",condition3);
assertTrue("string on failure",condition4);
assertTrue("string on failure",condition5);
```

would become

```
Matcher<Boolean> matchesTrue = IsEqual.equalTo(true);
collector.checkThat("String on Failure", condition1, matchesTrue);
collector.checkThat("String on Failure", condition2, matchesTrue);
collector.checkThat("String on Failure", condition3, matchesTrue);
collector.checkThat("String on Failure", condition4, matchesTrue);
collector.checkThat("String on Failure", condition5, matchesTrue);
```

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are looking for is called Soft Assertion, Try [assertj](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/)

```
    SoftAssertions soft = new SoftAssertions();
    soft.assertThat(<things>).isEqualTo(<other_thing>);
    soft.assertAll();
```

Soft assert will allow execution to next step without throwing exception at failure. At the end `assertAll()` method with throw all collected error at onece.

Comment: But is this applicable in Junit.... I thought this is testng stuff

Comment: AssertJ has JUnit as a dependency(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.5.1) so it should work, It just collects the exceptions and simply vomits all at once if it gets one.So the concept is definitely not bound with any unit test framework or language. In fact,here is the implementation of soft assert in python(http://pythontesting.net/strategy/delayed-assert), it exactly similar to what  @jeremiah  has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The other option here is a best practice that many people say you should be doing always anyway: only put **one** assert in each test case.

By doing so, each potential failure is somehow isolated from each other; and you directly get what you are looking for - as JUnit will tell you exactly, which tests failed and which passed. Without the need to introduce other concepts.

( you see, even if those other concepts like ErrorCollector or SoftAssertions are pretty easy and straight forward to use - they add a little bit of complexity to your code; making it a bit harder to read and understand )

Comment: In a *unit* test it's best to do only one assertion per test.  With tools like Selenium being brought into the mix the test is no longer a 'unit' level test because it must run against a live system. This is an 'integration' test.  At the integration level of testing the desire to isolate validations often comes at a price (time/performance/feedback), making the multi-assert facilities more acceptable.  It's all about the context that the test is oriented towards.  I don't disagree with your statement with regards to unit tests,but with integration that rule is not steadfast (in my experience)

Comment: ya.. i also thought about that.. But in many situations like verifying UI of small section ( for example- login page ) , multiple assertion makes sense. Also, above suggested solutions adds only 1 or 2 lines of code instead of much complexity